# HybridSource with AvroInputFormat in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

How do I use a [Hybridsource](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/hybridsource/) with the [AvroInputFormat](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/avro/)?
HybridSource requires a `Source` but `AvroInputFormat` extends `FileInputFormat` which is not accepted by `FileSource`. It looks like those are two completely distinct APIs. Is there a way to bridge this?